# What is the True Name of this function, which adds begin and end tokens with counters to a list of lists?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a feeling that this function must either be a standard thing, or be utterly misguided:

```
def leafcount(l):
    """
    count the size of each group in a tree, and insert begin and end markers with
    the group size
    """
    if isinstance(l, (list, tuple)):
        lst=[ "begin" + str(len(l))]
        lst.extend([leafcount(e) for e in l])
        lst.append("end" +str(len(l)))
        return lst
    else:
        return l
```

You can use it like this:

```
>>> leafcount([])
['begin0', 'end0']
>>> leafcount([1])
['begin1', 1, 'end1']
>>> leafcount([1,1,[1,1]])
['begin3', 1, 1, ['begin2', 1, 1, 'end2'], 'end3']
>>> leafcount([1,[1,1,1,[1,1]],[1,1]])
['begin3', 1, ['begin4', 1, 1, 1, ['begin2', 1, 1, 'end2'], 'end4'], ['begin2', 1, 1, 'end2'], 'end3']
```

I find it quite handy, particularly in combination with `flatten`, what should it be called?

Comment: keeping the state of something inside the container of that thing\ seems like a poor design to me. Because every time that thing runs, it outputs a lie, since it just changed the state of it all, no?

Comment: What purpose do the "markers" serve? Seems like that would add extra processing during insertion/lookup/etc to have to filter those back out of your actual data.

Comment: This seems like it really ought to be attributes on a class meant for this kind of storage if anything.

Comment: @CoryKramer It's part of the processing I'm doing, in this case I want  [1,[1,1,1,[1,1]],[1,1]] -> 1,4,4,4,8,8,2,2, which is very easy to calculate from the intermediate result with begin,ends in it. I could do that calculation as a single recursion, but it seems clearer and more debuggable with the three stages. But I do wonder if I've come up with a suboptimal way of solving a class of things there's a standard toolkit for, hence the question.

Comment: It's not standard, and has no standard name. Whether it's utterly misguided is a matter of opinion, but marking up data with strings inlined in the data itself looks very odd to me.

Comment: Do you want [1,[1,1,1,[1,1]],[1,1]] -> 1,4,4,4,8,8,2,2 or [1,[1,1,1,[1,1]],[1,1]] -> ['begin3', 1, ['begin4', 1, 1, 1, ['begin2', 1, 1, 'end2'], 'end4'], ['begin2', 1, 1, 'end2'], 'end3'] ?